# HTML email message condensed

Tags: php, html

The query below sends out an email.  It works okay, but the message is condensed into basically one long paragraph.  I would like a break where I have the `</br>` tags below.  However, the `</br>` tags are being ignored.  Any idea how I could put breaks there?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
        $message1 = "
    Someone made the following comment on your submission $submission:

    </br>

    $comment

    Please click the link below to see the comment in context.

    </br>

    $link1

    ";

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    $queryem = mail($mailaddress, "Someone has commented on your submission 
                            $submission.", $message1, $headers);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `br` tags introduce a *line break*, not a new paragraph.

If you want paragraphs, use `p`:

```
$message1 = "
<p>Someone made the following comment on your submission $submission:</p>
<p>$comment</p>
<p>Please click the link below to see the comment in context.</p>";
```

I assume you have sanitized `$comment`. If you haven't, the user can almost completely control how the e-mail will look like.

Answer (score 0):

Don't build MIME emails manually. As you can see, it's problematic and easy to break. Use someting like [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com) or [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) to do it for you. All you have to do is provide the content and addressing, and they'll take care of the headers/setup for you.

Answer (score -1):

`br` tags are written `<br/>`, not `</br>`. The first is an empty tag which signifies a line break. The second implies a closing tag for opening `<br>` which is unnecessary.

Comment: No, its `<br>`. It is HTML not XHTML.

Comment: Oh, and this just fixes the syntax error, it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: In that case, there's a missing opening `<br>`. But `<br/>` is not just for XHTML. It's not JUST a syntax error. A closing tag does nothing on it's own.

Answer (score -1):

Use `<br />` or `<br>` instead `</br>` for this purpose(inserting HTML new line), because  isn't HTML valid tag.

Comment: Duplicate of Michael Moir's answer, and this fixes the syntax error without touching on the actual problem.